# maven dependencies version conflict

Tags: maven, dependencies, conflict, apache-nifi

i want to build apache nifi from source like this: 
https://nifi.apache.org/quickstart.html
but it didn't work like this: 
[picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yBIVB.png)

pom.xml in nifi-assembly is this:`
https://github.com/apache/nifi/blob/master/nifi-assembly/pom.xml

Comment: Refer this  ->  [Maven Dependency Version Conflict Problem and Resolution](http://techidiocy.com/maven-dependency-version-conflict-problem-and-resolution/)

Comment: Have you tried running "mvn clean install" from the root of the source code? Also, your screenshot shows 1.5.0-SNAPSHOT, but master is at 1.6.0-SNAPSHOT right now, so I don't think your code is up to date.

Answer (score 0):

thank you all, my classmates said just leave it alone, just mvn clean install and it worked